# Jest exception in callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest to test js/Node code with callback function but Jest won't mark the test as 'failed' if `expect` fails in the callback function.

I have user.test.js as:

```
test('Create local user test@example.com', async () => {
   User.createLocal({email: "test@example.com"}, function(err, usr, options){
       expect(err).toBeNull();
       expect(options).toBeNull();    // this line fails correctly as options is not null
       expect(usr).not.toBeNull();
   })
});
```

When I run the test, Jest reports that it has received `JestAssertionError: expect(received).toBeNull()` and prints contents of the `options` (all good so far!) but it does not mark the test as failed. Instead Jest reports the test as PASSed:

```
PASS  model/user.test.js (9.005 s)
  √ Create local user test@example.com (12 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
```

If I raise `expect` from the main body of the function (i.e., not within the callback function) then Jest correctly marks the test as failed. But if `expect` fails within the callback then it just stops the test but it does not mark the test as failed.

What do I need to do so Jest marks the test as 'failed' as (I think) it should - even when `expect` is called within the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Jest does not wait for async code to be completed before finishing tests. See [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous) (particularly [on callbacks](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks)).

You can use `done` to let Jest know when to stop waiting for a test:

```
test('Create local user test@example.com', done => { // done added here
   User.createLocal({email: "test@example.com"}, function(err, usr, options){
       expect(err).toBeNull();
       expect(options).toBeNull();
       expect(usr).not.toBeNull();
       // The test will pass only if `done` is reached without a failed assertion:
       done();
   })
});
```

Comment: Won't this lead to Jest waiting 5 seconds (or whatever the default timeout is set to) for a failed result? I feel like creating a `new Promise(resolve => { ... })` and then awaiting said promise inside the callback would yield a more consistent result of failing immediately when an error is encountered rather than waiting for the timeout period.

Comment: From the (linked) docs: "If the expect statement fails, it throws an error and done() is not called". It will only cause a timeout in the code above if the callback is never called.